# PostgreSQL Query To Create A Directory

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Files are being written to a directory using the `COPY` query:

```
Copy (SELECT * FROM animals) To '/var/lib/postgresql/data/backups/2020-01-01/animals.sql' With CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

However if the directory `2020-01-01` does not exist, we get the error

> could not open file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/backups/2020-01-01/animals.sql" for writing: No such file or directory

PostgeSQL server is running inside a Docker container with the volume mapping `/mnt/backups:/var/lib/postgresql/data/backups`

The `Copy` query is being sent from a Node.js app outside of the Docker container.

The mapped host directory `/mnt/backups` was created by Docker Compose and is owned by `root`, so the Node.js app sending the `COPY` query is unable to create the missing directories due to insufficient permissions.

The backup file is meant to be transferred out of the Docker container to the Docker host.

**Question**: Is it possible to use an SQL query to ask PostgreSQL 11.2 to create a directory if it does not exist? If not, how will you recommend the directory creation be done?

*Using Node.js 12.14.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 host. Using PostgreSQL 11.2 inside container, Docker 19.03.5*

Comment: does this file need to be created in the server? would it be an option to create it directly in the client machine?

Comment: @JimJones It can be created directly in the client machine (Ubuntu, also the Docker host). Do you expect it to be significantly slower if created on the client machine?

Comment: there will be no difference in speed. i will add an answer for you to try it out

Comment: @JimJones There may be a difference in speed depending on the efficiency of the network and client. With `to stdin` the data must be transferred from the server to the client then to disk. With `to 'file'` it goes directly to disk.

Comment: [Postgres has its own backup and restore utilities](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html). They are likely to be a better choice than building your own.

Comment: @Schwern I need to backup the results of a certain query, such as `SELECT * FROM animals WHERE DATE_PART('month', "bornTimestamp") = 01 AND DATE_PART('year', "bornTimestamp") = 2020`. Wondering if there are backup/restore utilities that can support this?

Comment: @Schwern I agree, if the network is slow, the file transfer will also be slow. But I do believe that the OP does not intend to let this file in the server :) I mean, if the data is being exported, it will eventually leave the server :)

Comment: @JimJones Yes, it is meant to reside outside of the database server. Sorry for not making this clearer

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to solve it is to create the file directly into the client machine. Using `STDOUT` from `COPY` you can let the query output be redirected to the client standard output, which you can catch and save in a file. For instance, using [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html) in the client machine:

```
$ psql -U your_user -d your_db -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM animals) TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER ','" > file.csv
```

Creating an output directoy in case it does not exist:

```
$ mkdir -p /mnt/backups/2020-01/ && psql -U your_user -d your_db -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM animals) TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER ','" > /mnt/backups/2020-01/file.csv
```

**On a side note**: try to avoid exporting files into the database server. Although it is possible, I consider it a bad practice. Doing so you will either write a file into the postgres system directories or give the postgres user permission to write somewhere else, and it is something you shouldn't be comfortable with. Export data directly to the client either using `COPY` as I mentioned or follow the advice from @Schwern. Good luck!

Comment: Just tried your command, seems like `psql` does not create the directories for you. `/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /mnt/backups/2020-01/animals.sql: Directory nonexistent`. Is there an argument we can pass to `psql` or must we use `mkdir -p <dirname>` before running the `psql` command?

Comment: Nope, just wondering if everything can be neatly done in 1 single command.

Comment: Well, I would go for writing `mkdir -p your_directory_path` before the `psql` command. This would create the directory for you in case it does not exist

Comment: @Nyxynyx I just added a line to my answer that might to what you want:) good luck

Comment: Thanks. I've also modified the `psql` command to use multi-threaded compression with `psql .... | pigz -rsyncable > /mnt/backups/2020-01/animals.csv`

Answer (score 1):

[Postgres has its own backup and restore utilities](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html) which are likely to be a better choice than rolling your own.

> When used with one of the archive file formats and combined with pg_restore, pg_dump provides a flexible archival and transfer mechanism. pg_dump can be used to backup an entire database, then pg_restore can be used to examine the archive and/or select which parts of the database are to be restored. The most flexible output file formats are the “custom” format (-Fc) and the “directory” format (-Fd). They allow for selection and reordering of all archived items, support parallel restoration, and are compressed by default. The “directory” format is the only format that supports parallel dumps.

A simple backup rotation script might look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

table='animals'
url='postgres://username@host:port/database_name'
date=`date -Idate`
file="/path/to/your/backups/$date/$table.sql"

mkdir -p `dirname $file`

pg_dump $url -w -Fc --table=$table -f $file
```

To avoid hard coding the database password, `-w` means it will not prompt for a password and instead look for [a password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html). Or you can use any of [many Postgres authentication options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html).